# Retrieving data from a secure website using iphone app with username and password

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to create an app for my school that allows the student to access their online student account information such as courses, grades and financial aid. I need to pull the data from the site according to which student logs on. How can I fetch that data pertaining to the student who logs into the app?

Comment: Please share code that you tried??

Comment: If you already have a web service as the service endpoint, say a Restful API, you can use `RestKit` to contact with the server.